# Withdraw XMR from exchange EXMO, and deposit to Monero GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, integrated-address, transfer

I want report you my first experience regarding XMR withdrawal from EXMO.
They say:

> (EXMO.com)
>
> Jun 5, 12:15 BST
>
> Hello!  We withdraw XMR only to the integrated address, that is, those
>   in which the Payment ID is already entered, and if you have an address
>   for which you need a separate id, then Monero will not be able to be
>   displayed on it.  In order to find out your Payment ID you need to
>   follow the link:  https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html  In the
>   line at number 8, enter the number of your XMR wallet on EXMO, click
>   Check Address and in the line at number 10 (the 3rd field) will be
>   your payment id, and in the line at number 15 the standard wallet
>   address.  Thank you for contacting us!

How can I get an integrated address?
I want to withdraw XMR from EXMO to the Monero GUI.
I have to generate a receiving address using the Monero GUI and then insert it on EXMO. Is it right?  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line wallet (`monero-wallet-cli`) to create an integrated address.

```
[wallet 45xxxx]: help integrated_address 
Command usage: 
  integrated_address [<payment_id> | <address>]

Command description: 
  Encode a payment ID into an integrated address for the current wallet public address (no argument uses a random payment ID), or decode an integrated address to standard address and payment ID
```

So launch the cli like:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file path/to/your/wallet
```

Then run the command:

```
integrated_address
```

Which will then print out an integrated address with a random payment ID.

Alternatively, you can use [xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) to create an integrated address as follows:

1. In the dropdown at the top left, select 'XMR integrated'
2. Paste your standard public address in box #8
3. Click 'Check Address'
4. Copy the output in the boxes next to 'Decoded:' and paste them into boxes #5 and #6 respectively
5. Click 'Random' next to the 'Payment ID:' box
6. Click 'Gen 7.'

You now have an integrated address in box #7. You can double check you have done this all correctly by then clicking 'Sent to 8.' followed by clicking 'Check Address'. The boxes next to 'Decoded:' should not change if you have done all this correctly.

Note that integrated addresses are being phased out in favor of subaddresses. So consider using an exchange that properly supports Monero.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ask you to have a little patience because this crypto world is quite new for me. And also sorry for my English. If you don't explan me step by step like a little child where and how write command, I don't be able to follow your instructions. For the future and because of this problem, you would be so kind to indicate me one or more exchange fully compliant to MONERO trading? Waiting for your reply. Have a nice week.

Comment: Is there anyone that can help me to withdraw my 2.5 XMR from EXMO?

Comment: @jtgrassie - I find it dangerous to recommend putting your seed into that tool to merely generate an integrated address. You don't need to touch the private keys to generate one.

Comment: I agree with you. Write my 24 seed keys words should be dangerous. So, how can I have an integrated XMR Monero Address?

Comment: You say: "You can use the command line wallet (monero-wallet-cli) to create an integrated address."
I am not able to follow your instructions due to my lack of computer skills. If you write to me step by step in an elementary way what should I do I try to follow the instructions in the hope of succeeding.

Comment: @Giovani - I have written detailed steps in the answer on how to create an integrated address, *without* inputting seed/keys. At no point in steps 1-6 are your private keys/seed used.

Comment: Hi jtgrassie, I have followed your instruction. I show you step by step when I stop and i'm not be eable to proceed. Thanks for your support.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EXsk-I910wA9VAa81BDl8oRBEF0OJVKA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i
I WOULD BE VERY GREAT IF YOU SHOULD INDICATE ME ONE OR MORE SITES OF EXCHAGE BTC/XMR THAT DO NOT REQUEST THIS INTEGRATED ADDRESS AT WITHDRAWAL TIME. THANKS

Comment: 1) The link you posted doesn't work. 2) LocalMonero.

Comment: Ok got the link working. You followed the instructions correctly for the alternative instructions I gave and created an integrated address. But you are then, incorrectly, trying to use the cli (which you don't need to use anyway as you have created an integrated address using the website).

Comment: And for the cli instructions, you are not using it correctly at all. You have not started it with the wallet-file parameter as detailed in the answer so it is prompting you to create a new wallet, which you are trying to name the command "integrated_address...". The whole reason I posted the *alternative* instructions is because you are clearly a not used to command line apps so would need A LOT of help learning that first, and that is too broad a question.

Comment: ok, last question: please, can you create for me an integrated address? you can see in the link EXMO wallet XMR address, you can see also ID . If you need further data I can provide. Otherwise I don't try to withdraw my 2.5 XMR from EXMO wallet.

Comment: You can also help me for this request:i I WOULD BE VERY GREAT IF YOU SHOULD INDICATE ME ONE OR MORE SITES OF EXCHAGE BTC/XMR THAT DO NOT REQUEST THIS INTEGRATED ADDRESS AT WITHDRAWAL TIME. THANKS

Comment: I've already suggested an exchange I know that doesn't require/use integrated addresses. And I have detailed the steps (two different ways) to create an integrated address from a standard address. If your address in box 15 is your standard address, the integrated address in box is good to use.